# No desktop Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, xorg

I installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop and I'm having a problem, after the login option nothing happens.

The things is that I uninstalled Unity 8, and now I can see the desktop when using NVIDIA drivers, but whatever I want to use Xorg drivers (mainly for battery life), nothing happens after the login screen.

After doing some research seems that people are having issues with NVIDIA drivers, but it seems that in my case, it's the contrary, so I could use some help.

Thanks.

edit 1 : 
Reinstalling Xorg using :

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg-* xserver-xorg; sudo apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg; sudo dpkg-reconfigure xorg.
```

and the desktop environment :

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-desktop; sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Works, but i have to do it at every start

edit : uninstalling unity 8 is not the problem since i had the problem with both cards before deleting it, and deleting unity 8 , just let me use unity 7

Comment: How did you uninstalled Unity 8? That may have removed something related to the Intel Graphics.